# ¿Donde encuentro la clase sprite de java?

Tags: java, clase, animación

quiero hacer animaciones para videojuegos e intento hacerlo con la clase sprite, pero cuando lo busco en el IDE de netbeans no me aparece.

me puede ayudar alguien

Comment: yo no se si java cuenta con una clase `Sprite` como tal pero una clase `Sprite` suele ser para manejar las imagenes y sus posiciones ect, con lo cual usted podria crear su propia clase. Ahora le pregunto si lo que usted quiere hacer es un videojuego y tratandose de java puede mirar alguna libreria para ello puede mirar LibGDX -> https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ quizas le ayude, aqui algunos videos por si es lo que busca -> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=libgdx+tutorial+espa%C3%B1ol. Saludos

Comment: ¿Has leído el [tutorial de Netbeans al respecto](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingJavaMEGamesWithGameBuilder)? Al final de la página también te indican más enlaces.